# Not able to style my otp component in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, one-time-password

I have used bachdgvn/vue-otp-input to insert otp component but I am not able to style it. It doesnt respond to any changes I make in the style tag

I used https://www.vuescript.com/password-otp-input/ for reference

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <p id="header">OTP</p>
    <p id="text">We have sent you a 4 digit verification code in the given mobile number.</p>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" class="otp-container">
      
      <v-otp-input
        ref="otpInput1"
        inputClasses="otp-input"
        separator="-"
        :num-inputs="6"
        :should-auto-focus="true"
        input-type="number"
        @on-change="handleOnChange"
        @on-complete="handleOnComplete"
      />
    
    <button id="otp-submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>      
</template>
```

the style is applied all the inputs using props

```
props: {
   inputClasses: {
      type: String,
    }
}
```

finally uses the style tag

```
<style scoped>
.otp-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: where did you registered your `vue-otp-input` component?

Comment: in main.js  `import OtpInput from "@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input";
Vue.component("v-otp-input", OtpInput);`  @HardikShah

Answer (score 0):

Your styles being scoped and `v-otp-input` being a vue component, that means it won't be affected.

You can use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) to achieve this.

There is multiple ways to select a child component in a scoped style tag:

```html
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
::v-deep .a { /* ... */}
.a /deep/ .b { /* should be deprecated by now */ }
</style>
```